# Get target element from Vue directive

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  <div @click="onClick(target??)">click me</div>
</template>

<script>
...
onClick(t){
  console.log(t)
}
...
</script>
```

Can I retrieve target(DOM element) of directive event inside the directive like above?

Comment: `$event.target`?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks